# Improve execution time of query in PostgreSQL with multiple joins

Tags: postgresql, index, join

I'm having the trouble with the following query due to the growing size of the database ( websites is around a million rows, misspelled goes up to a couple millions )

It can reach up to 165 seconds in run time, I was wondering if there was a way to improve this without having to add additional columns to the tables, maybe using some king of index ?

```
SELECT contacturl, url 
FROM websites 
WHERE contactable = true
  AND websites.contacted = false 
  AND url IN (
    SELECT url
    FROM scans
    WHERE scanid IN (
      SELECT distinct(scanid)
      FROM misspelled
      WHERE word = ?
    )
  )
;
```

Edit : 
As requested, the output of the explain analyze :

[image]

Edit (1) :
After Checking the explain statement output, this sing select seems to be taking most of the time :

```
select distinct(scanid) from misspelled where word = ?
```

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions . Please edit the post (edit link bottom left of post) then comment here when done. At minimum add `explain analyze` output.

Comment: Thanks, if you require anything else please let me know.

Comment: Any chance of putting the text of the plan up not a screenshot, or pasting to explain.depesz.com? Manually comparing stats estimates is a bit of a pain.

Comment: Here it is : http://explain.depesz.com/s/EGBT

Answer (score 1):

Try going with an `EXISTS` test. First, let's be explicit about where the columns are coming from, also you don't need `col = TRUE` and `col = FALSE` on bools. You can simply say `WHERE col` or `WHERE NOT col`, I think that's a bit cleaner.

```
SELECT w.contacturl, w.url 
FROM websites AS w
WHERE w.contactable
  AND NOT w.contacted
  AND w.url IN (
    SELECT s.url
    FROM scans AS s
    WHERE s.scanid IN (
      SELECT distinct(m.scanid)
      FROM misspelled AS m
      WHERE m.word = ?
    )
  )
;
```

Now, with `EXISTS`,

```
SELECT w.contacturl, w.url 
FROM websites AS w
WHERE w.contactable
  AND NOT w.contacted 
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM scans AS s
    WHERE s.scanid IN (
      SELECT distinct(m.scanid)
      FROM misspelled AS m
      WHERE m.word = ?
    )
    AND w.url = s.url
  )
;
```

But you can do even better. DISTINCT just reduces duplicates for IN. With `EXISTS` duplicates are simply ignored.

```
SELECT w.contacturl, w.url 
FROM websites AS w
WHERE w.contactable
  AND NOT w.contacted 
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM scans AS s
    WHERE w.url = s.url
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM misspelled AS m
      WHERE m.scanid = s.scanid
      AND m.word = ?
    )
  )
;
```

That should be a lot faster, normally.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `IN` with `JOIN` might do the trick.

```
WITH s1 AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT scanid
   FROM misspelled
   WHERE word = ?),
     s2 AS
  (SELECT url
   FROM scans
   JOIN s1 USING (scanid))
SELECT contacturl,
       url
FROM websites
JOIN s2 USING (url)
WHERE contactable = TRUE
  AND websites.contacted = FALSE;
```

Probably need many indexes:

- `word` ON `mispelled`
- `url` ON `websites`
- `contactable` AND `contacted` ON `websites`

AND without CTEs (although I am not sure if it will improve performance):

```
SELECT contacturl,
       url
FROM websites
JOIN
  (SELECT url
   FROM scans
   JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT scanid
      FROM misspelled
      WHERE word = ?) s1 USING (scanid)) s2 USING (url)
WHERE contactable = TRUE
  AND websites.contacted = FALSE;
```

Comment: Use of a CTE here is likely to be extremely bad for performance. Use subqueries in FROM instead. PostgreSQL's CTEs are (unfortunately) optimisation fences.

Comment: Thanks, Performance got a little bit better, from 160 seconds to 60 seconds I think but it's still not enough.

Comment: I am sorry but 160-> 60s is not a little better. It is 3 times faster=300% improvement which is impressive. Realize that it cannot be improved by SQL rewrite. You do a JOIN on text values (url). Could not you use urlID?

Comment: Oh I know, I did not mean in anyway to under-mind your solution, an x3 improvement is quite something. But it happens that we have a dozen of these queries which are supposed load on a webpage. so you can understand which it's still not enough for this scenario. I'll have to go over the DB Schema and see if I can do something.

Comment: Actually, I re ran the tests with the same conditions ( I have a memory leak on my PC ) and I got the same results for both queries : 

Before : http://explain.depesz.com/s/EGBT

After : http://explain.depesz.com/s/wFa4

I also tried adding a urlid, same thing